# How to align cells/columns with CSS for XML table?

Tags: css, xml, alignment

I'm trying to complete this exercise and am stuck. HTML would be so much easier, but it's a CSS and XML exercise. I need to align the cells from the first row (has borders) with the cells from below (no borders). I have tried column properties, header, caption, and nothing quite gets it. Thanks in advance. BTW, I can only modify the CSS file. If the three first cells have solid borders without the cyan exposed, it would work. It's pretty ugly as is, but as close as I can get it to render.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="final.css"?>
<document>
  <headers>
    <header>First Name</header>
    <header>Last Name</header>
    <header>Loan Amount</header>
  </headers>
  <mortgages>
    <mortgage>
      <firstName> Ryan </firstName>
      <lastName> Folks </lastName>
      <amount>$200,000</amount>
    </mortgage>
    <mortgage>
      <firstName>  Edward </firstName>
      <lastName> Jordan </lastName>
      <amount>$220,000</amount>
    </mortgage>
    <mortgage>
      <firstName> Desmond </firstName>
      <lastName> Smith </lastName>
      <amount>$230,000</amount>
    </mortgage>
    <mortgage>
      <firstName> Terrell </firstName>
      <lastName> Wilson </lastName>
      <amount>$240,000</amount>
    </mortgage>
    <mortgage>
      <firstName> Julius </firstName>
      <lastName>  Smith  </lastName>
      <amount>$250,000</amount>
    </mortgage>
  </mortgages>
</document>

document{
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 3px solid black;
    table-layout:auto;
    margin: 2em;
    }
headers
{
display: table-row;
text-align:center;
background-color: cyan;
}
header
{display:table-header;
border: 3px solid black;
}
mortgage
{
display: table-row;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
firstName, lastName, amount{
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align:center
    }
```

Comment: Prateek, so close!! It does not render the same way in Firefox, or Opera, which is a requirement. Can you or someone modify it to work correctly in Firefox? I shall keep trying as well. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Modified CSS :

```
document{
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 3px solid black;
    table-layout:auto;
    margin: 2em;
    }
headers{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: cyan;
}
header
{ 
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align:center;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
mortgage{
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
firstName, lastName, amount{
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align:center
}
```

Refer [this solution](http://tinkerbin.com/mjXc4DRG).

I have updated the code to make it look better.

Comment: An answer should explain a solution and, when appropriate, illustrate it with included code. A link alone is not an adequate answer.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : Its not a link to another solution, its kind of fiddle which I have created, and I have also included the solution in my comment as well.